# Custom "account" pages

Tags: ubercart, users, path-aliases

I am creating custom account management pages in drupal with quite a few criteria. The first being that there is a page at `/account` which contains two separate forms: 1) To enter a new email address and a confirm new email address 2) To enter a new password and confirm new password

I'd like other pages for example `/account/orders` to view past orders and `/account/billing` to edit credit card data and billing address (I'm using ubercart and authorize.net for e-commerce and credit card processing, respectively) How can I access the billing data (address and last 4 digits of credit card number) from ubercart?

What are some general tips for this? Should I create a custom "account" module? Should I just try to edit some existing templates somehow? I know I'm asking a lot of big questions, and I'm not asking for a complete answer. Just some general advice and ideas.

Also, I hate the user account pages with numbers in them identifying the user. It seems simple enough just to have it know depending on who is logged in (i.e. `/user/5/edit` vs. `/user` or `/user/edit`

Comment: you may wanna try to create your pages such as orders and billing with Views, it has a good integration as far as I know with Ubercart. and of course you can always try some custom solution such as module implementation or whatever but try to see if you can make it work with Rules/Views

Answer (score 1):

You will have to work on custom module implementation.

Custom solution would not effect content on `account` page.

`hook_menu` will define the menu items like `account/orders` and `account/billing`

If you are using Ubercart then you will have to carefully investigate if your required information are being stored and in which table. I am not sure if Ubercart stores Credit Cards data. I think Ubercart uses DPM (Direct payment method) to process cards which totally happens on Authorize.net pages.

`Pathauto` normally defines url alias also for user profile pages. But I think there is no way to skip user id from url while editing a user.